# How i can filter a portion of html code after ajax success

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have this piece of code that shows me the the url page and that what im expecting.

```
$.ajax({
url: 'http://example.com',
dataType: 'html',
dataFilter: function(filter){

   return filter.document.getElementsByTagName('script');
   },
   error: function() {
  $('#info').html('<p>An error has occurred</p>');
},
success: function(response) { 
    $('#div').html(response); 
   },
 })
```

the thing is that i have to apply some filter to result page (like extracting some content with some specific tag).
Can you please tell me if i can apply it directy to `$('#div').html(response);`or if i can apply it with dataFilter or is there other simple way to do this.

Thanks

Comment: What do u mean by this **Can you please tell me if i can apply it directy to $('#div').html(response);**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry if i wasn't clear enough in my question.
I maneged to get I was thinking to do, which was filtering some content of the ajax call.

Here is the code if it can solve any problem.

```
 success:function(response) { 
            html = $(response);

            $('#loader').remove();

            html.each(function(i, el){
            var resources = $(el).filter('script');
            if(resources.attr('src')!==undefined ) {
            $('.code:last').append('\n'+resources.attr('src'))
            }

        })
 }
```